# How to access an instance variable of a parent class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to access a class variable defined in the parent class constructor. Here is the code.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = 0

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def func(self):
        print self.x

s = B()
s.func()
```

This gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'x'
```

If I try changing the `func()` to

```
def func(self):
    print x
```

then I get error:

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

If I try changing the `func()` to

```
def func(self):
    print A.x
```

Then I get the error

```
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'x'
```

Now I am running out of ideas.. What's the correct way to access that class variable `x` in the parent class `A`? Thanks!

NOTE: I am working only on the "class B" part of my project, hence I can't really go modify class A and change the way variables are defined. That's the only constraint.

Comment: `x` is *not* a class variable.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a local variable with instance variables with class variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be `self.x`, not just `x`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
```

---

Just a quick note - even from other methods of `A` would be the `x` not accessible:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = 0
    def foo(self):
        print(self.x) # <- will not work
        print(x) # <- will utimately not work
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it as `self.x = 0` instead of `x = 0` - otherwise it's just a local variable.

If you cannot modify `A`, what you are trying to do is impossible - there is absolutely no way to access that value, not even with black magic (if your method was *called* by that method, you could probably do nasty things with the stack to get its value)

Comment: Please see the note at the bottom of my question.

Comment: In that case what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: AFAIK not even the blackest kind of black Python magic lets you access a local variable from a function unless it is in your call stack (which is not the case here).

Comment: I think some black magic containing a debugger and stealing the value from local namespace could do it, but that's not the way how things should be done.

Comment: But he cannot do that after the method has executed - it'll be gone. Probably you could get it from the GC but if it's really just an integer he has no way of knowing that it is the value he's looking for (for a function it'd be quite easy)

Comment: But `A.__init__` is called from `B.__init__` so there is some space to setup something malicious :)